# Preferred methods for business entity validation in the enterprise

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, design-patterns, c#-4.0

Let me preface this question and state that using Entity Framework is not an option for us.

In our financial organization we have business entities that are going to be used across solutions. Some have a UI others do not. Validation and business rules must be contained within the entity.

I code against a DAL and DTOs that are generated for me and those DALs use procs to operate CRUD on the DB (could be SQL could be Oracle).

So as I am creating MVC, WCF, Console apps etc.. the question has been nagging if a better method of validation could be implemented.

Here is a couple typical properties in an entity object:

```
[DefaultValue("")]
public string Branch {
    get { return _branch; }
    set {
        if (value != null && value == _branch) return;
        const string propertyName = "Branch";
        ValidationInstance.Clear(propertyName);
        ValidationInstance.ValidateRequired(propertyName, value);
        ValidationInstance.ValidateNumeric(propertyName, value);
        ValidationInstance.ValidateLength(propertyName, value, 2);
        _branch = value;
        if (EntityState != EntityStateType.New)
            EntityState = EntityStateType.Changed;
    }
}

    [DefaultValue(0)]
public decimal HighDefermentMargin {
    get { return _highDefermentMargin; }
    set {
        if (value == _highDefermentMargin) return;
        const string propertyName = "HighDefermentMargin";
        ValidationInstance.Clear(propertyName);
        ValidationInstance.ValidateRange(propertyName, value);
        _highDefermentMargin = value;
        if (EntityState != EntityStateType.New)
            EntityState = EntityStateType.Changed;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a mix of data annotations and explicit calls to a validation class to perform increasingly detailed validation.

In an MVC app we painstakingly duplicate validation on the ViewModel so we get client side and server side validation. Here is the ViewModel version of the same property from above:

```
[Required]
[Range(0.0, 99.99)]
[Display(Name = "High Deferment Margin")]
public decimal HighDefermentMargin { get; set; }
```

The main difference here is that the validation in the entity loads the errors into an errors collection on the Validation class which can be queried at the time the entity goes to save itself. If(!IsValid) then throw a custom exception that contains the array of errors. The controller loops thru them and adds them to ModelState.

I'm starting to work on some classes that have literally a couple hundred fields. Even if they get broken down by OO the number of fields is still very high. These are loan certifications etc that have a lot of data for a single record. Having to write out validation on that many properties makes me want to vomit. I can't just write a utility to generate the entities and validation because business rules are what drive the validation, not the database. Meaning a field may be nullable in the db but not allowed to be persisted as null based on business rules, or the field can be null but only if a separate field has a value, etc..

So, can using just the data annotations in the View Model AND the entity the same way achieve the same results? I can write custom validators for the non-standard validation and then business rules for more complex stuff. Will validation errors bethrown up to a higher level from the entity so the UI can inform the user in the same friendly way as ModelState? What are others doing in this same kind of situation?

Comment: I have a suggestion. While encountering the invalid inputs or any situation in which the rule is not fulfilled while validating via the Business rule engine, just bubble the exception so that it can be caught in the Controller and then added to the modelstate's error collection. For example: throw a custom exception and donot catch that exception in the Rules Engine, just re-throw till it reaches the controller. Then show in the UI using Html.ValidationSummary().

Comment: That would work - but the idea is to get away from evaluating the property in a set or get and to provide a more AoP design pattern. I've already got a strategy in the property to collect the error. All throwing an exception does is provide a different way to show the error to a caller. That's just swapping code for different code. I'd like to eliminate code from the properties.

Comment: Built in types default to required, you don't need to add that attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a validation attribute on a property **can get different validation results** (validation passing or not) depending if it is evaluated in the UI Layer, BUsiness Layer or DAL. Consider for instance a Required attribute if applied on the ViewModel it can fail, but then in the Business Layer it can pass simply because the value that the user has not provided has been provided from other sources.
However, validation rules like the format of an email...always get the same result. However, there are scurity issues that may required the validation to be repeated in the business layer...simply because the web server is more exposed to attacks and is more vulnerable. However, repeating twice the same validation doesn't imply writing twice the code. You can collect all attributes that you would like to apply in several layers in a common dll where you define [MetaDataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679243.aspx)s that you apply to the various versions (ViewModel, BL, DAL) of the same conceptual entity. This way, you fulfill security requirements without duplicating code.

As suggested by saravanan you can use exceptions to communicate validation errors discovered in other layers to the UI Layer (you can also configure WCF to communicate exception details to the client)

Comment: That's an interesting tactic. I'll have to learn more about MetaDataTypes and see if that can achieve what I'm looking for. Not sure if it would be a problem but my ViewModels are typically subsets of multiple entities and don't map 1:1. You're right in assuming I want a hardened entity to re-validate even if it passes the UI. For example if the UI was compromised and the ViewModel sets an entity to an "active" status. The Business Rules and validation in the entity would evaluate and negate the attack. I need so see some concrete examples of a good alternative strategies.

Comment: "ViewModels are typically subsets of multiple entities and don't map".
You can apply Just 1 MetaDataType to each object, so I suggest to do this way: instead of mixing the properties of several objects into an unique root class, I define a root ViewModel. Each property of such root ViewModel contains a child viewmodel whose properties are a subset of the properties of JUST ONE BL object. This way each child ViewModel may have is different MetadataType.
A property that is a combination of several property (like a sum of prices for instance is put directly in the root model or wgere you want

Comment: This way each child ViewModel has a subset of the properies contained in the MetadataType applied to it. Now...for a kind  design error if the metadatatype is not able to find ALL ITS PROPERTIES in the object it is applied to, it throw an exception(difficult to understand why???). However I have written a custom DataAnnotationsMetaDataprovider that overcomes this problem. I put it in the my open source project "Mvc Controls Toolkit", however if you need just the DataAnnotationMetaDataProvider I can send you A stand alone file that you can install in your project

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm actually doing that already so It looks like I'm in line to achieve it. How does the validation get handled at the time of persistence? Currently, with the validationclass with an errors collection I can do:
        public void Save(string username) {
            if (!IsDirty) return;
            if (!IsValid)
                throw new ELMValidationException("Errors", ErrorList);
And send the ErrorList up to the controller and add them to ModelState. How do I evaluate at the time of save when using the attributes? Is there an error bag concept to check?

Comment: The custom provider sounds like a good starting point if you don't mind sending. cdsmith72 at me dot com

Comment: I will send it in the weekend...I would like to be sure I have removed all dependencies from other classes.

Comment: No problem at all thanks alot, I appreciate your answer, I've been reading about metadatatypes today and believe it's the cleanest way I've run across and provides the AoP concepts I'm looking for. I'm marking you as answered for the credit.

Comment: "How do I evaluate at the time of save when using the attributes? Is there an error bag concept to check"
There is a static class called Validator class that has methods for the job of attribute validation. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382130.aspx...if you google a little you can find also some example of use...because the official documentation is....not so good

Comment: I sent you the code...let me know if you received it...not 100% sure about your EMail :)

Comment: I didn't receive it yet. I added my email address to my profile description text as it looks as if I can't add it here in comments due to restrictions. But I'll try again: cdsmith72@me.com

Comment: Yes I received it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @FrancescoAbbruzzese: Can you forward that code for my knowledge also. I am sure that i can learn from it. My email id is in my profile. Can we use code contracts from Microsoft for pre & post validations or Business rules based validation on entities.

Comment: not found your email. tried to "transform" your web site into an email it was wrong.